# Third party login (Sign in with AppleId/ Sign in with Google) not working inside WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, third-party-cookies

I have sample app which used Wkwebview and we're loading social platform for login.
When we load login page of any social platform let say Twitter, LinkedIn or Instagram. The web page is loaded and login page is shown of respective platform.
In the login page there are multiple login options like sign with apple or sign with google, But when cliking of those third party login buttons we didn't get any response from wkwebview (like callbacks).
For sign in with appleId straight forward shows something went wrong toast on webview.
Can someone help why this is happening on wkwebview?